# Filtering a hash of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash of hash that I need to filter. I did find how to do a lookup but it did not answer my question.

Say I have a hash of hash like that :

```
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
        town      => "springfield"
    },
    jetsons => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    simpsons => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
        town      => "springfield",
    },
);
```

I lets say I want all the townfolks from springfield. I want the same hash of hash in output without the outsiders.

```
my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
        town      => "springfield"
    },
    simpsons => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
        town      => "springfield",
    },
);
```

It seems silly but can't figure out how to filter the struture. The goal would be to iterate on all the people of springfield after filtering.

I of course did some research and the closest thing I came by is hash slices.
But they seem scary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first need to find the keys of the elements you want to remove:

```
grep { $HoH{$_}{town} eq 'springfield' } keys(%HoH)
```

Then you delete them:

```
delete $HoH{$_} for grep { $HoH{$_}{town} eq 'springfield' } keys(%HoH);
```

Or using a hash slice:

```
delete @HoH{ grep { $HoH{$_}{town} eq 'springfield' } keys(%HoH) };
```

Comment: In the `grep` you're treating strings (`keys %HoH`) as hashrefs.

Comment: As always, cleaner and more elegant than the solution I was working on. I imagine you can write this stuff in your sleep.

Comment: The var I get is a ref so the line becomes : delete $HoH->{$_} for grep { $HoH->{$_}{town} eq 'springfield' } keys(%{$HoH})

Comment: Still what is this syntax? Can I do something like print $_ for ('test1', 'test2')

Comment: Yes. It's called a "statement modifier". Documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to `grep` or `map` through hashes, then you can consider to use `grepp` or `mapp` from [List::Pairwise](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Pairwise). Advantage is that there's no need to mention the original hash variable anymore in the grep/map code block, making it more "functional". So your problem could be solved like this:

```
use List::Pairwise qw(grepp);
%HoH = grepp { $b->{town} eq 'springfield' } %HoH; # $a is the current key, $b is the current value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for my $key (keys %HoH) {
delete $HoH{$key} if(!$HoH{$key}{town});
                    (OR)
delete $HoH{$key} if($HoH{$key}{town} !~ m/springfield/);
}
```

Use any one of the **delete option** you will get your answer...