# Ansible looping through dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have a json data structure that looks like this.

```
"napalm_interfaces_ip": {
   "GigabitEthernet0/0": {
       "ipv4": {
           "10.23.160.110": {
               "prefix_length": 22
           },
           "10.23.160.114": {
               "prefix_length": 22
           }
       }
   },
   "GigabitEthernet1/0/1": {
       "ipv4": {
           "10.23.160.112": {
               "prefix_length": 22
           }
       }
   }
},
```

I want to use Ansible to find the interface that has a specific IP address assigned.

I thought I could use *with_dict* to loop through the dictionary and *when* to find the interface with the IP that matches.  Something like this...

```
- name: Testing with_dict
  debug:
    msg: "Interface is {{ item.key }}"
  when: 10.23.160.114 == item.value.ipv4.keys()
  with_dict: "{{ napalm_device_data.ansible_facts.napalm_interfaces_ip }}"
```

This isn't going to work though as item.value.ipv4 is a dictionary and really what I want to do is compare each of the keys in item.value.ipv4 against the IP address.  I think i need a way to loop through the dictionary within the dictionary but I'm not 100% sure.

I do not want to flatten the data structure.  I am just looking for a way to reference the key of a dictionary within a dictionary.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how this is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494605/flattening-and-filtering-a-complex-structure-in-ansible-dict-of-list-of-dict?  Can you elaborate on this?  I am not asking to flatten the data structure.  Thanks.