# Ansible double loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a data list in an yml file.
I would like to extract data, using a double loop, like we use to do.
This is an example of my list

> `[a,b,c] 
>   vm1:
>     -a 
>     -b 
>   vm2: 
>     -a 
>     -c
>   vm3: 
>     -b`

This is for a generic deployment purpose.
I need to loop the list, and for each element, get the list of the vm that need to be installed in.
For example

```
a > vm1 vm2 

b > vm1 vm3

 c > vm2
```

I tried with_nested but it doesn't help.
Any idea to deal with that?

Comment: What does your playbook look like? What did your attempt using `with_nested` look like? How did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496367/2795592).

Here's modified JMESPath:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    mylist: [a,b,c]
    myvms:
      vm1:
        - a
        - b
      vm2:
        - a
        - c
      vm3:
        - b
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} > {{ list_with_keys | json_query(qry) | join(',') }}"
      vars:
        list_with_keys: "{{ myvms | dictsort | to_json | from_json }}"
        qry: "[?contains([1],`{{ item }}`)][0]"
      with_items: "{{ mylist }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "a",
    "msg": "a > vm1,vm2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "b",
    "msg": "b > vm1,vm3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "c",
    "msg": "c > vm2"
}
```

Comment: thank you. how can i get this form : a : vm1 and a : vm2

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can always replace `debug` with `set_fact` and construct a dict with keys a,b,c and then iterate over it with `with_subelements`.

Comment: i wanted to convert from a > vm1 , vm2 to separate lines like a : vm1 and a : vm2