# JMESpath expression to filter object by property and return list of object names having this property set

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

Is it possible to write JMESPath expression to return a list of object names where a specific subproperty value is set? In the example below I'd like to get a list of all hostsnames where **fileexists.stat.exists** is set to true.

My goal is to use Ansible hostvars structure to get a list of all hosts where a specific file is present.

```
{
"hostvars": {
    "oclab1n01.example.org": {
        "fileexists": {
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "stat": {
                "exists": false
            }
        }
    }, 
    "oclab1n02.example.org": {
        "fileexists": {
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "stat": {
                "exists": true
            }
        }
    }, 
    "oclab1n03.example.org": {
        "fileexists": {
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "stat": {
                "exists": true
            }
        }
    }
} }
```

In this example I'd like to get the following output

```
["oclab1n02.example.org", "oclab1n03.example.org"]
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41579581

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer (TL;DR)

Yes, this is possible, but it is extremely cumbersome, because, at least in terms of working with JMESpath, the source dataset is **poorly normalized** for this kind of general-purpose query.

### Context

- jmespath query language
- querying object properties for deeply nested objects

### Problem

- How to construct a jmespath query with filter expressions
- The goal is to filter on objects with arbitrarily nested object properties

### Solution

- This can be done with jmespath, but the operation will be **cumbersome**
- One problematic issue: the source dataset is **poorly normalized** for this kind of jmespath query
- In order to construct the jmespath query, we have to assume all the primary object keys are known **in advance** of creating the query
- In this specific example, **we have to know that there are three and only three hostnames in advance of constructing the jmespath query** ... this is not a favorable circumstance if we want the flexibility to specify any arbitrary number of hostnames

### Example

The following (way-too-huge) jmespath query ...

```
  [
    {
      "hostname": `oclab1n01.example.org`
      ,"fileexists_stat_exists":  @.hostvars."oclab1n01.example.org".fileexists.stat.exists
    }
    ,{
      "hostname": `oclab1n02.example.org`
      ,"fileexists_stat_exists":  @.hostvars."oclab1n02.example.org".fileexists.stat.exists
    }
    ,{
      "hostname": `oclab1n03.example.org`
      ,"fileexists_stat_exists":  @.hostvars."oclab1n02.example.org".fileexists.stat.exists
    }
  ]|[? @.fileexists_stat_exists == `true`]|[*].hostname
```

returns the following desired result

```
  [
    "oclab1n02.example.org",
    "oclab1n03.example.org"
  ]
```

### Pitfalls

- One major pitfall with this use-case is the source dataset is **poorly normalized** for this kind of query
- A more flattened data structure would be easier to query
- Consequently, if possible, a better approach would be to **flatten the source dataset** before running jmespath queries against it

#### Alternate example with a different original dataset

If the original data were organized as a list of objects, instead of a set of nested objects within objects, it would be easier to search, sort and filter the list without having to know **in advance** how many hostname entries are involved.

```
{"hostvars": [
    {"hostname":"oclab1n01.example.org"
      ,"fileexists":        true
      ,"filechanged":       false
      ,"filefailed":        false
      ,"filestat_exists":   false
      ,"we_can_even_still_deeply_nest":{"however":
           {"im_only_doing":"it here","to":"prove a point"}
         }
     }
    ,{"hostname":"oclab1n02.example.org"
      ,"fileexists":        true
      ,"filechanged":       false
      ,"filefailed":        false
      ,"filestat_exists":   true
     }
    ,{"hostname":"oclab1n03.example.org"
      ,"fileexists":        true
      ,"filechanged":       false
      ,"filefailed":        false
      ,"filestat_exists":   true
     }
  ]
}
```

The above **re-normalized** dataset can now be easily queried

```
hostvars|[? @.filestat_exists == `true`]|[*].hostname
```

Comment: Why do you think that a "key -> record" relationship is poorly normalized? It seems very idiomatic in configuration management software such as salt and ansible, yet I do find that most jinja filters and, as I've learned today JMESPath work great for `[val1, val2, val3] | map(f) -> [f(val1), f(val2), f(val3)]`, but no so much for `{key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3} | map(f) -> {key1: f(val1), key2: f(val2), key3: f(val3)}`. Is this somehow fundamentally hard to implement?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP **//Why [...] a "key -> record" relationship is poorly normalized//** Only for this specific context, not in general. As you mentioned, it is a routinely-encountered data pattern. The matter here is avoiding to fight against JMespath, vs working with it. **//Is this somehow fundamentally hard to implement//** Not fundamentally. The issue is whether the designer(s) chose to make mapping data type iterable, just like list type. It is just a design decision. Feel free to think similar to relational databases, where "rows" (list) are easier to iterate than columns "mapping".